# windowSoftInputMode="adjustResize" not working with translucent action/navbar jetpack compose

Tags: android, android-jetpack-compose, android-jetpack

I got a problem where when I set: true inside my themes.xml and I have android:windowSoftInputMode="adjustResize" inside my Manifest the android:windowSoftInputMode="adjustResize" does not do its job anymore, and when I comment out true the adjustResize works again, I saw a lot of answers and nothing worked for me in Jetpack compose, are there people that know how to fix the problem?

I tried: WindowCompat.setDecorFitsSystemWindows(window, false)
window.statusBarColor = Color.Transparent.toArgb()
But this also makes it so adjustResize doesnt work.
I tried: android:fitsSystemWindows="true" but that also didnt do anything for me